# Android: Extending RelativeLayout

Tags: android, custom-view, viewgroup

I have a class extending RelativeLayout like so:

```
class CustomLayout extends RelativeLayout {

  CustomLayout(Context context) {
      super(context, null, 0);
  }

  CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs, 0);
  }

  CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

}
```

I make use of this layout through the XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"            
     xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"        
     android:layout_width="match_parent"        
     android:layout_height="match_parent"           
     android:orientation="vertical">            
      <com.vj.myapp.CustomLayout        
           android:id="@+id/imageView_container"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"        
           android:layout_height="0dp"        
           android:background="#555"        
           android:layout_weight="1">                    
      </com.vj.myapp.CustomLayout>     
</LinearLayout>
```

But the app crashes with:

```
Error inflating class com.vj.myapp.CustomView
```

I did provide the required constructors.
What's going on?

Comment: By the way, how do i format android code properly in my post?

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: `Error inflating class com.vj.myapp.CustomView` where is CustomView??

Comment: Sorry, meant CustomLayout. @Floem It's solved now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make them public.  The constructors have to be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Android Studio the easiest may is hit ctrl+o and choose methods to override. It will generate stubs with correct signatures, then you can modify code as you wish.